# How do i check for windows credential prompt and fill it in automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-credential-provider

How do i check if i am being prompted for windows credentials in c# windows forms and fill in the prompt and click ok automatically?

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite following your question.  Can you describe things a little more clearly?

Comment: Probably his application needs some admin account and asking for credential. He is asking if i can fill them from my application. The basic answer is "no, you can't" :)

Comment: @ArgeKumandan why not?

Comment: Because that's something beyond your application. OS related thing. There is a reason windows pops that's dialog. Reason is security. And if you can do that you can consider yourself as "i hacked the windows": Because that's a security vulnerability. And if u post that to the microsoft security team you would probably get good money for that ;) Consider that logging in windows without knowing password. Pretty much same thing

Comment: It is not safe to let a program fill in the credentials. This would mean that operators could bypass this security by starting a program. That would make it vulnerable for hacker attacks. If you don't want the credentials window, make sure you don't do anything that needs the credentials, or start the program as a user with the proper rights.

Comment: i know that. i am having a problem with a third party application that is supposed to cache the credentials for the session, but after 5 minutes they are no longer cached. trying a work around.